# TempData["Mensagem"] erro na runtime dizendo que o objeto está nulo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5

Comecei faz pouco tempo com ASP.NET MVC, e como podem ver estou jogando na instrução if,else o `tempData[]`
e o que ocorre é um seguinte, toda vez que vou clicar dentro do else em "View in Page Inspector" ele me dá um erro na janela, é o mesmo erro na hora do Debug, apenas uso essa opção "View in Page Inspector" do Visual Studio para não ter que esperar rodar e etc. Neste "View in Page Inspector" ele me mostra logo na janela ao lado sem precisar rodar o código, me mostrando se vai funcionar ou não.
Ele me retorna esta mensagem:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Já pesquisei bastante e enfim, pelo o que me responderam, apenas me disseram que o TempData está com valor nullo, pois antes está ao invés de:

```
TempData["Mensagem"].ToString() != ""
```

estava

```
TempData["Mensagem"].ToString() != null
```

Já vi algumas respostas que não esclareceram muito bem, cheguei até usar um `NullReferenceException();` lançando essa excpetion depois do else, mas um outro programador
em outro lugar me respondeu que não seria recomendável eu usar assim.
Como posso resolver este erro?

Está imagem abaixo é do meu projeto aberto:

[image]

```
**<!--MAIN-->
    <div class="main">

        <section class="container">
            <a onclick="javascript:FecharPopup()" href="@Ecommerce.Code.UrlMaker.UrlHome()" class="FecharPopup"></a>

                <article class="linha1">
                    <h1>
                        @if (TempData["Mensagem"].ToString() != "")
                        {
                            @Html.Raw(TempData["Mensagem"].ToString());
                            <figure><img src="/Content/Images/Mensagem/erro.png" alt=""/></figure>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //throw new ArgumentNullException();
                            @Html.Raw(TempData["Mensagem"].ToString());
                            <figure><img src="/Content/Images/Mensagem/sucess.png" alt=""/></figure>   
                        }
                    </h1>
                </article>

            <article class="linha2">
                <p>Em caso de dúvidas, <a target="_parent" href="@Ecommerce.Code.UrlMaker.UrlCentralAtendimento()">fale conosco.</a></p>
            </article>

        </section>
    </div>**
```

Comment: Oi, Raffa, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Acertei a formatação da sua pergunta, é melhor [usar o Markdown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) que HTML ao publicar aqui. Fiquei numa dúvida, o código contém esses `**` ou você tentou fazer bold nele?

Comment: Olá, obrigado, não acho que coloquei de maneira errada estes ** !

Comment: Ok, é minha ignorância da linguagem então ;)

Comment: Não entendi ???

Comment: Não, sem problemas, eu achei estranho, mas se é normal tá tudo ok. Não mexi nisso ao editar pois não tinha certeza, só queria confirmar. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 3):

Vamos analisar a seguinte linha do ponto de vista do compilador:

```
TempData["Mensagem"].ToString() != ""
```

Ela se traduz da seguinte maneira:

- Obtenha o valor da propriedade indexada relativa à chave "Mensagem" da coleção `TempData`;
- Converta este valor para `string`;
- Me diga se o valor convertido é diferente de uma string vazia ("").

O problema reside entre o primeiro e segundo passos. O valor retornado a partir da coleção TempData é nulo, e nulo não pode ser convertido para string.

Uma possível solução é a seguinte:

```
(TempData["Mensagem"] ?? "").ToString() != ""
```

`??` é o operador de aglutinação (*coalesce operator*). A sequência agora funciona da seguinte maneira:

- Obtenha o valor da propriedade indexada relativa à chave "Mensagem" da coleção `TempData`;
- Caso o valor seja nulo, assuma que o valor é uma string vazia ("").
- Converta este valor para `string`;
- Me diga se o valor convertido é diferente de uma string vazia ("").

Comment: Vou tentar isso, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Tente :

```
**<!--MAIN-->
    <div class="main">

        <section class="container">
            <a onclick="javascript:FecharPopup()" href="@Ecommerce.Code.UrlMaker.UrlHome()" class="FecharPopup"></a>

                <article class="linha1">
                    <h1>
                        @if (TempData["Mensagem"] != null)
                        {
                            @Html.Raw(TempData["Mensagem"].ToString());
                            <figure><img src="/Content/Images/Mensagem/erro.png" alt=""/></figure>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.Raw("<b>Sucesso.</b>");
                            <figure><img src="/Content/Images/Mensagem/sucess.png" alt=""/></figure>   
                        }
                    </h1>
                </article>

            <article class="linha2">
                <p>Em caso de dúvidas, <a target="_parent" href="@Ecommerce.Code.UrlMaker.UrlCentralAtendimento()">fale conosco.</a></p>
            </article>

        </section>
    </div>**
```

Isso pode resolver porque você checa se tem algum valor antes de tentar converter ele pra string.. o que você estava fazendo é convertendo nada pra string e isso gerava o erro.

Comment: Pode explicar porque seu código resolve o problema? Confira o guia [answer] para mais detalhes.

Comment: O que significa estes ("<b>sucess.</b>") pode me dar mais detalhes, por favor !

Comment: esse success foi só um exemplo de como o seu programa poderia prosseguir caso existisse valor dentro do TempData.

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui resolver meu próprio erro.
O codigo está assim agora, comparado ao de cima, que coloque antes !
O eu queria realmente, era trazer a mensagem que estava vindo do `TempData["Mensagem"]`
e fazer uma comparação, para poder identificar se a mensagem erra de erro ou de sucesso. No caso, creio que esta mensagem deve vir de uma **BLL** pois estou com a parte do projeto `branch` aqui e não a `trunk` a original então não consigo ver da onde vem a mensagem original. No `@if` a comparação que está agora esta certo, a que estava antigamente, estava errada pois eu estava comparando o tempData 2 vezes, e por isto me retornava o erro:

> **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

na comparação antiga estava assim:

> **1:**

```
   @if (TempData["Mensagem"].ToString() != "")
               {
               @Html.Raw(TempData["Mensagem"].ToString());
               <figure><img src="/Content/Images/Mensagem/erro.png" alt=""/></figure>
               }
               else
               {
               //throw new ArgumentNullException();
               @Html.Raw(TempData["Mensagem"].ToString());
               <figure><img src="/Content/Images/Mensagem/sucess.png" alt=""/></figure>   
                }
```

Veêm a diferença ?
Tanto que quando dava este erro `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` eu
lançei uma `Exception` de maneira errada, usei essa: `NullReferenceException` mas não era aconselhevál usar já que só funcionaria da hora do runtime, de qualquer forma essa `Excpetion` não resolveria meu problema.
A comparação de qual `mensagem` é ou o que está passando se errada ou não, ele já faz no `@if`. O que eu queria realmente mesmo era a `img.png` mais estava jogando 2 vezes a `@Html.Raw` e o `tempData` de novo depois do else olhem:

> **2**

```
   else
   {
   //throw new ArgumentNullException();
   @Html.Raw(TempData["Mensagem"].ToString());
   <figure><img src="/Content/Images/Mensagem/sucess.png" alt=""/></figure>   
   }
```

Jogando e comparando duas vezes sendo que o `@Html.Raw` só precisava passar uma vez, e a comparação viria na imagem mesmo, mas como ? usando `QueryString`
Cada `Controller` tem a sua `ActionResult`, neste caso algumas das Actions nas `Controllers` usavam `JsonResult` vou exemplificar com um codigo do projeto aqui para vocês entenderem, vou mostrar uma `JsonResult` dentro de uma `Controller`, depois ainda tem o arquivo **`JS`** na pasta **Scripts**, olha este **JsonResult**:

> **3**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CadastrarCliente(ClienteEntity cliente)
    {
        string mensagem = string.Empty;

        string url = url = Code.UrlMaker.UrlCentralCliente();

        bool retorno = ClienteBLL.CadastrarCliente(cliente, out mensagem);

        //Guarda a mensagem que será exibida
        TempData["Mensagem"] = mensagem;

        return Json(new { RedirectUrl = url, Retorno = retorno });
    }
```

Observam, ali no **bool retorno** se for true ela vai guardar a mensagem, como falei a mensagem deve estar vindo de uma **`BLL`**, mas não tenho como ver aqui, pois não estou com o codigo original do projeto, apenas um **codigo cópia**, para poder passar ao original e subir em produção.
Ele verifica no **`ClienteBLL.CadastrarCliente()`** se foi com sucesso ou não, independente do que for, ele vai guardar a mensagem no tempData["Mensagem"], e vai me retornar esta mensagem pelo:

> **4**

```
 return Json(new { RedirectUrl = url, Retorno = retorno });
```

Esqueçam este `RedirectUrl` apenas no **`Retorno`**

Porém ainda tem o Arquivo **`JS`** como ele ainda vai saber qual é a `View` que deverá exibir esta mensagem ? aqui está:

> **5**

```
    function RetornoPostCadastro(json) 
    {
    $.ExibirMensagem('/Base/Mensagem?retorno=' + json.Retorno, 400, 445);
    }
```

Algumas fotos para vocês verem, olha a pasta **Views** da `Base Controllers` e dentro uma View **Mensagem**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra foto para olharem, olhem a **`BaseController.cs`** e logo em baixo a **`Views, Base, Mensagem`**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde **`Base`** é nome da Pasta de uma **`Controller`** e `Mensagem` é o nome da **View** que ela devrá exibir, e usando **Query String** `?retorno=' + json.Retorno` da onde ? lembram ? este json.Retorno vem dá:

> **6**

```
   return Json(new { RedirectUrl = url, Retorno = retorno });
```

Olhem ali `Retorno = retorno` onde esta variável **`retorno`** vem dá **(variavel bool retorno = ClienteBLL.CadastrarCliente()** olhem na parte **`3`**:

> **7** **Código da View Mensagem**

```
<div class="main">

    <section class="container">
   <a onclick="javascript:FecharPopup()" href="@Ecommerce.Code.UrlMaker.UrlHome()" class="FecharPopup"></a>

     <article class="linha1">
        <h1>
           @if (TempData["Mensagem"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["Mensagem"].ToString()))
                {
                 @Html.Raw(TempData["Mensagem"].ToString());
                 }
                 <figure>
                 @if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["retorno"] == "true")
                  {
                  <img src="/Content/Images/Mensagem/sucess.png" alt=""/>
                  }
                  else
                  {
                  <img src="/Content/Images/Mensagem/erro.png" alt=""/>    
                  }
                 </figure>
         </h1>
       </article>

       <article class="linha2">
         <p>Em caso de dúvidas, <a target="_parent" href="@Ecommerce.Code.UrlMaker.UrlCentralAtendimento()">fale conosco.</a></p>
       </article>

     </section>
   </div>
 <!--MAIN-->
```

**É isso, obrigado aos que responderam e espero que a minha dúvida que tive e que conseguir, e junto com os outros posts de respostas aqui, ajudem a outros com dúvidas parecidas, abraço**